# How to get only latest record from different ranges?

Tags: mysql, range

I am looking at a case in which we have a number of tanks filled with liquid. The amount of liquid is measured and information is stored in a database. This update is done every 5 minutes. Here the following information is stored:

- tankId
- FillLevel
- TimeStamp

Each tank is categorized in one of the following 'fill-level' ranges:

- Range A: 0 - 40%
- Range B: 40 - 75%
- Range C: 75 - 100%

Per range I count the amount of events per tankId.

```
SELECT sum(
        CASE
            WHEN filllevel>=0 and filllevel<40 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Range A',
        sum(
        CASE
            WHEN filllevel>=40 and filllevel<=79 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Range B',
        sum(
        CASE
            WHEN filllevel>79 and filllevel<=100 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS 'Range C'
FROM TEST ;
```

The challenge is to ONLY count the latest record for each tank. So for each tankId there is only one count (and that must be the record with the latest time stamp).

For the following data:

```
insert into tank_db1.`TEST` (ts, tankId, fill_level) values 
('2017-08-11 03:31:18', 'tank1', 10),
('2017-08-11 03:41:18', 'tank1', 45),
('2017-08-11 03:51:18', 'tank1', 95),
('2017-08-11 03:31:18', 'tank2', 20),
('2017-08-11 03:41:18', 'tank2', 30),
('2017-08-11 03:51:18', 'tank2', 80),
('2017-08-11 03:31:18', 'tank3', 30),
('2017-08-11 03:41:18', 'tank3', 45),
('2017-08-11 03:51:18', 'tank4', 55);
```

I would expect the outcome to be (only the records with the latest timestamp per tankId are counted):

```
- RANGE A: 0
- RANGE B: 1 (tankdId 3)
- RANGE C: 2 (tankId 1 and tankId2)
```

Probably easy if you are an expert, but for me it is real hard to see what the options are.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the number of tanks or also the name of the tanks?

Comment: "Just" the total number of tanks per range. However if a list of tank names is easy I might be able to use that :-)

Comment: The value for range `B` should be `2` as there is also `tankId=4`.

Comment: Sharp eyes!. tankId=4 is indeed a typo (but it should work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the latest per group timestamp value:

```
select tankId, max(ts) as max_ts
from test
group by tankId;
```

**Output:**

```
    tankId  max_ts
--------------------------------
1   tank1   11.08.2017 03:51:18
2   tank2   11.08.2017 03:51:18
3   tank3   11.08.2017 03:41:18
4   tank4   11.08.2017 03:51:18
```

Using the above query as a derived table you can extract the latest per group `fill_level` value. This way you can apply the logic that computes each range level:

```
select sum(
    CASE
        WHEN t1.fill_level>=0 and t1.fill_level<40 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Range A',
    sum(
    CASE
        WHEN t1.fill_level>=40 and t1.fill_level<=79 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Range B',
    sum(
    CASE
        WHEN t1.fill_level>79 and t1.fill_level<=100 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Range C'
from test as t1
join (
   select tankId, max(ts) as max_ts
   from test
   group by tankId
) as t2 on t1.tankId = t2.tankId and t1.ts = t2.max_ts
```

**Output:**

```
    Range A Range B Range C
---------------------------
1   0       2       2
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/HRDD77910)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I am impressed, that would have cost me at least a day 
 full of headache to figure that out.Am going to try and implement it. Let you know that result later on!

Answer (score 1):

I get a different result (oh, well, same result as GB):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fill_level < 40 THEN x.tankid END) range_a
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fill_level BETWEEN 40 AND 75 THEN x.tankid END) range_b
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fill_level > 75 THEN x.tankid END) range_c
  FROM test x
  JOIN (SELECT tankid,MAX(ts) ts FROM test GROUP BY tankid) y
    ON y.tankid = x.tankid AND y.ts = x.ts;
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| range_a | range_b     | range_c     |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| NULL    | tank3,tank4 | tank1,tank2 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

EDIT:

If I was solving this problem, and wanted to include the tank names in the result, then I'd probably execute the following...

```
   SELECT x.* 
     FROM test x 
     JOIN 
        ( SELECT tankid,MAX(ts) ts FROM test GROUP BY tankid) y
       ON y.tankid = x.tankid 
      AND y.ts = x.ts
```

...and handle all the other problems, concerning counts, ranges, and missing/'0' values in application code.

Comment: This includes that names of the tanks as well. I am pretty sure I will use that info as well. Thanks

Comment: @Jeroen I only wrote it this way to illustrate the point that your result set was wrong. If you actually want to incude the names in the result, then, personally, I'd go about it a slightly different way. I can elaborate, but essentially I'm of the view that there is (almost) no instance where it's appropriate to use GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) in a working query.

Comment: Yes I made a typo and created another tankId. Why would the GROUP_CONCAT not be used and what other way would be more appropriate?

Comment: See EDIT above. The GROUP_CONCAT issue relates to the scalability of the query and the flexibility/malleability of the result set.